# Converting a nested loop calculation to Numpy for speedup

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, floating-point

Part of my Python program contains the follow piece of code, where a new grid
is calculated based on data found in the old grid.

The grid i a two-dimensional list of floats. The code uses three for-loops:

```
for t in xrange(0, t, step):
    for h in xrange(1, height-1):
        for w in xrange(1, width-1):
            new_gr[h][w] = gr[h][w] + gr[h][w-1] + gr[h-1][w] + t * gr[h+1][w-1]-2 * (gr[h][w-1] + t * gr[h-1][w])
    gr = new_gr

return gr
```

The code is extremly slow for a large grid and a large time *t*.

I've tried to use Numpy to speed up this code, by substituting the inner loop
with:

```
J = np.arange(1, width-1)
new_gr[h][J] = gr[h][J] + gr[h][J-1] ...
```

But the results produced (the floats in the array) are about 10% smaller than
their list-calculation counterparts.

- What loss of accuracy is to be expected when converting lists of floats to Numpy array of floats using *np.array(pylist)* and then doing a calculation?
- How should I go about converting a triple for-loop to pretty and fast Numpy code? (or are there other suggestions for speeding up the code significantly?)

Comment: Can you explain what those loops do?

Comment: With arrays you can (and should) index with `gr[h, J]`.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I understand this is supposed to be faster.

Comment: @hellpanderrr a new grid is calculated based on a long calculation where muliple values of the old grid is used. The grid is a part of my game engine.

Comment: Please explain what your given code is (and is supposed to be doing).  It looks like you are applying a smoothing kernel to re-grid your data... please explain further.

Comment: Please write the entire calculation being done inside the innermost loop.

Comment: What are you focusing on now - accuracy or speed?

Comment: From the part of the calculation you've shown, it looks like you might be able to do this with matrix multiplication, which ought to be much faster than a loop, if it will work.  What is the entire calculation?

Comment: The whole code is `gr[h][w] + gr[h][w-1] + gr[h-1][w] + t * gr[h+1][w-1]-2 * (gr[h][w-1] + t * gr[h-1][w])

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question with that code snippet. Hope that's okay.

Comment: If the grid is a 2D list of floats, `gr[h][J]` wouldn't have worked. What other changes did you make in your NumPy attempt?

Comment: Also, you never make a new `new_gr`, so most of your iterations are using the same object for `gr` and `new_gr`. That's going to cause a lot of error in your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `gr` is a list of floats, the first step if you are looking to vectorize with NumPy would be to convert `gr` to a NumPy array with [`np.array()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Next up, I am assuming that you have `new_gr` initialized with zeros of shape `(height,width)`. The calculations being performed in the two innermost loops basically represent `2D convolution`. So, you can use [`signal.convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) with an appropriate `kernel`. To decide on the `kernel`, we need to look at the scaling factors and make a `3 x 3` kernel out of them and negate them to simulate the calculations we are doing with each iteration. Thus, you would have a vectorized solution with the two innermost loops being removed for better performance, like so -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Get the scaling factors and negate them to get kernel
kernel = -np.array([[0,1-2*t,0],[-1,1,0,],[t,0,0]])

# Initialize output array and run 2D convolution and set values into it
out = np.zeros((height,width))
out[1:-1,1:-1] = signal.convolve2d(gr, kernel, mode='same')[1:-1,:-2]
```

**Verify output and runtime tests**

Define functions :

```
def org_app(gr,t):
    new_gr = np.zeros((height,width))
    for h in xrange(1, height-1):
        for w in xrange(1, width-1):
            new_gr[h][w] = gr[h][w] + gr[h][w-1] + gr[h-1][w] + t * gr[h+1][w-1]-2 * (gr[h][w-1] + t * gr[h-1][w]) 
    return new_gr

def proposed_app(gr,t):
    kernel = -np.array([[0,1-2*t,0],[-1,1,0,],[t,0,0]])
    out = np.zeros((height,width))
    out[1:-1,1:-1] = signal.convolve2d(gr, kernel, mode='same')[1:-1,:-2]
    return out
```

Verify -

```
In [244]: # Inputs
     ...: gr = np.random.rand(40,50)
     ...: height,width = gr.shape
     ...: t = 1
     ...: 

In [245]: np.allclose(org_app(gr,t),proposed_app(gr,t))
Out[245]: True

Timings -

In [246]: # Inputs
     ...: gr = np.random.rand(400,500)
     ...: height,width = gr.shape
     ...: t = 1
     ...: 

In [247]: %timeit org_app(gr,t)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.13 s per loop

In [248]: %timeit proposed_app(gr,t)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. @hpaulj also helped me understand this

Answer (score 2):

@Divakar, I tried a couple of variations on your `org_app`.  The fully vectorized version is:

```
def org_app4(gr,t):
    new_gr = np.zeros((height,width))
    I = np.arange(1,height-1)[:,None]
    J = np.arange(1,width-1)
    new_gr[I,J] = gr[I,J] + gr[I,J-1] + gr[I-1,J] + t * gr[I+1,J-1]-2 * (gr[I,J-1] + t * gr[I-1,J])
    return new_gr
```

While half the speed of your `proposed_app`, it is closer in style to the original.  And thus may help with understanding how nested loops can be vectorized.

An important step is the conversion of `I` into a column array, so that together `I,J` index a block of values.

Comment: I like that broadcasted indices with one column array and another row array and also the fact that it's closer to original code.