# Iterating over multidimensional Numpy array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

What is the fastest way to iterate over all elements in a 3D NumPy array? If `array.shape = (r,c,z)`, there must be something faster than this:

```
x = np.asarray(range(12)).reshape((1,4,3))

#function that sums nearest neighbor values
x = np.asarray(range(12)).reshape((1, 4,3))

#e is my element location, d is the distance
def nn(arr, e, d=1):
    d = e[0]
    r = e[1]
    c = e[2]
    return sum(arr[d,r-1,c-1:c+2]) + sum(arr[d,r+1, c-1:c+2]) + sum(arr[d,r,c-1]) + sum(arr[d,r,c+1])
```

Instead of creating a nested `for` loop like the one below to create my values of `e` to run the function `nn` for each pixel :

```
for dim in range(z):
    for row in range(r):
        for col in range(c):
            e = (dim, row, col)
```

I'd like to vectorize my `nn` function in a way that extracts location information for each element (`e = (0,1,1)` for example) and iterates over ALL elements in my matrix without having to manually input each locational value of `e` OR creating a messy nested for loop.  I'm not sure how to apply `np.vectorize` to this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `array[dim,row,col] = someValue` instead? Are you assigning the same value `someValue` to all its elements? Consider posting sample input, ouput for demonstrating what you have in mind?

Comment: Additionally, in NumPy, the fastest way is to *not* iterate at all, but do operations in a vectorized manner. Whether you could do so or not would depend on the intended operation itself that you would like to perform within each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Now, for a *proper* vectorization and thus a noticeable speedup, the actual implementation of `nn` needs to be known. For a general case, [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) could be looked into.

Comment: `np.sum(x[n[0] - d:n[0]+d+1,n[1]-d:n[1]+d+1])/27` maybe? Where's the averaging step? Also, check the ranges?

Comment: `pix` has 3 values, but `n` in `nn` only uses 2.  Is `d` supposed to vary as well, or is it always 1?  `nn()` returns a `(3,3,z)` shaped array, but `array` (bad name) accepts just 1 element.  (close to the edge `nn()` returns a 0 element array).

Comment: You need to turn this into a small working example, not just a hypothetical one.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to vectorize over the `d` dimension:

```
def nn(arr, e):
        r,c = e  # (e[0],e[1])
        return np.sum(arr[:,r-1,c-1:c+2],axis=2) + np.sum(arr[:,r+1,c-1:c+2],axis=2) + 
            np.sum(arr[:,r,c-1],axis=?) + np.sum(arr[:,r,c+1],axis=?)
```

now just iterate over the row and col dimensions, returning a vector, that is assigned to the appropriate slot in `x`.

```
for row in <correct range>:
    for col in <correct range>:
        x[:,row,col] = nn(data, (row,col))
```

The next step is to make

rows = [:,None]
   cols = 
   arr[:,rows-1,cols+2] + arr[:,rows,cols+2] etc.

This kind of problem has come up many times, with various descriptions - convolution, smoothing, filtering etc.

We could do some searches to find the best, or it you prefer, we could guide you through the steps.

[Converting a nested loop calculation to Numpy for speedup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320370/converting-a-nested-loop-calculation-to-numpy-for-speedup)

is a question similar to yours.  There's only 2 levels of looping, and sum expression is different, but I think it has the same issues:

```
for h in xrange(1, height-1):
   for w in xrange(1, width-1):
      new_gr[h][w] = gr[h][w] + gr[h][w-1] + gr[h-1][w] +
               t * gr[h+1][w-1]-2 * (gr[h][w-1] + t * gr[h-1][w])
```

Comment: plus One for the link

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing.  Since I'm returning the `xv` vector and slipping it in to the larger 3D array `lag`, this should speed up the process, right?  `data` is my input dataset.

```
def nn3d(arr, e):
    r,c = e

    n = np.copy(arr[:,r-1:r+2,c-1:c+2])
    n[:,1,1] = 0

    n3d = np.ma.masked_where(n == nodata, n)

    xv = np.zeros(arr.shape[0])
    for d in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if np.ma.count(n3d[d,:,:]) < 2:
            element = nodata
        else:
            element = np.sum(n3d[d,:,:])/(np.ma.count(n3d[d,:,:])-1)
        xv[d] = element

    return xv

lag = np.zeros(shape = data.shape)        
for r in range(1,data.shape[1]-1): #boundary effects
    for c in range(1,data.shape[2]-1):
        lag[:,r,c] = nn3d(data,(r,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably [`array.nditer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html):

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for x in np.nditer(a):
    print(x, end=' ')
```

which prints

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```